# lighttpd virtual hosting configuration

Tags: virtualhost, lighttpd, centos6, virtualization

I need help setting up virtual hosting in lighttpd.
i have the lighttpd default webpage in `/var/www/lighttpd` dir and i have created other dirs for my other websites `/var/www/web1.com/public_html` and `/var/www/web2.com/public_html`

I have tried to follow the documentation page on lighttpd websites and other guides online but haven't been successful. I just want to know what file do i edit and what do i add to be able to serve websites from the other virtual hosts/dirs?

full configuration is too long but here is what i added to default lighttpd.conf

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^www\.(.*)$" {
  url.redirect-code = 301
  url.redirect = (
    "/(.*)" => "http://%1/$1"
  )
}


$HTTP["host"] == "www.web1.com" {
#url.redirect  = (
#    "^/(.*)" => "http://web1.com/$1",
#  )
    server.document-root = "/var/www/web1.com/public_html"
#    accesslog.filename = "/var/www/web1.com/logs/error.log"
}

$HTTP["host"] == "web2.com" {
    server.document-root = "/var/www/web2.com/public_html"
#    accesslog.filename = "/var/www/web2.com/logs/error.log"
}

$HTTP["host"] == "web3.com" {
    server.document-root = "/var/www/web3.com/public_html"
#    accesslog.filename = "/var/www/web3.com/logs/error.log"
}
```

Comment: can someone help?

Comment: Can you provide the configuration you currently have?

Comment: i am just starting from the default configuration..the configuration file is pretty long...and its same as default configuration...i have tried and tried different things but didn't work so reverted back to default now

Answer (score 1):

You'll want some configuration along these lines:

```
$HTTP["host"] == "web1.com" {
    server.document-root = "/var/www/web1.com/public_html"
}
$HTTP["host"] == "web2.com" {
    server.document-root = "/var/www/web2.com/public_html"
}
```

That should be all that's needed to get those two directories mapped to those two host headers.  If that doesn't work, can you go into more detail about what kind of problems you're seeing when attempting to use this config?

**Edit:**

To have the `www` domains redirect to non-www, use a configuration like this:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^www\.(.*)$" {
  url.redirect-code = 301
  url.redirect = (
    "/(.*)" => "http://%1/$1" 
  )
}
```

Comment: well you can check the config i have here and did NOT work http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showpost.php?p=8493934&postcount=17

Comment: tried yours and didn't work either...did you check my config file http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showpost.php?p=8493934&postcount=17

Comment: @redhatengineer6 Can you expand on what you mean by "didn't work"? Does the service start successfully, or with any errors during the start process?  What steps are you taking to test?  What happens when you try to access the server with a web browser - connectivity errors, HTTP errors, not getting the expected content?

Comment: here is the errors from the error.log in /var/log/lighttpd/error.log file http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showpost.php?p=8494007&postcount=23

Comment: how to go to next line and enter codes on serverfault?

Comment: @redhatengineer6 See [here](http://serverfault.com/editing-help).  Those fastcgi errors should have no bearing on your ability to serve static content.  Can you please give more detail on what you're observing when attempting to use a browser to load content from one of these hostnames?

Comment: am still not getting the code and line break...i did 4 spaces for code didnt work and i did 2 spaces for break and didnt work...Now for web1.com i was able to see the index.html file in /var/www/web1.com/public_html/ and same for web2.com...now for web3.com i have wordpress installed and everything is setup but i get error 500 and 503...also i have php-fpm enabled so just so you know the setup and am using centos6

Comment: also web1.com works fine but www.web1.com goes to default lighttpd page..same as www.web2.com and www.web3.com...so how do i make www.web1.com and web1.com both go to the page i want? (URL redirect)

Comment: @redhatengineer6 Edit your question with content that needs special formatting, which is not allowed in comments.  Do you want the `www` versions to redirect to the non-www versions, or simply serve the same content?  Your fastcgi errors are relevant to the failures for the wordpress site; what's your fastcgi configuration?

Comment: i want `www` redirect to `non-www` and for php-fpm i used this guide http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-lighttpd-with-php5-php-fpm-and-mysql-support-on-centos-6.3 to setup php-fpm which is up and running

Comment: I tried this link, just like many other useless links on lighttpd, redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/howtoredirectwww and all it did was have www and non-www to show the same content but that is not what the intentions are..i want www to redirect to non-www

Comment: help still wanted here ppl

Comment: @redhatengineer6 See edited answer for redirecting `www`.  Make sure you've removed any handling of the `www` domains from your existing configuration before putting that in.

Comment: @shane-maden did you see the link i used to setup php-fpm? anything i need to edit/add to have the wordpress working on web3.com?       also why is the lighttpd website that useless?

Comment: ok i added the code for the redirect and didn't work...also do i just add that code without any changes or do i custom it for each domain? you didn't mention that.

Comment: @redhatengineer6 Can you edit your question with your current full configuration?

Comment: i edited the question now..also i try to add @shane-madden at the beginning but it always disappears after i submit my comment..why?

Comment: @redhatengineer6 It automatically notifies me because this comment is under my answer.  Can you clarify what you mean by the redirect not working?  What behavior are you seeing from client browsers accessing the `www` site?  You seem to still have `$HTTP["host"] == "www.web1.com"` configured, which won't work correctly since that has `www` in it; the `www` redirect host should be the only thing handling those.

Comment: well how come i see mine @redhatengineer6 and yet i can't see urs? well i just foundout something here...the www.web1.com actually was able to redirect to www..both www and non-www redirected to www (i want opposite) and the others web2.com and web3.com all redirected to www and showed the default lighttpd index page....now when i changed the www.web1.com back to web1.com then it started to behave like web2.com and web3.com, showing the default lighttpd default index page..kinda weird. So what you think is wrong here?

Comment: @redhatengineer6 That.. is interesting.  So just to be clear -- when you enter `web2.com` in a browser, the address in the bar changes to `www.web2.com`, then it loads the content from the default lighttpd document root?

Comment: yes that is correct and i just tried that with web3.com...i changed that also to www.web3.com and then it started showing the error 500 and 503 pages..when i change back to web3.com then it loads the default lighttpd page..all www and non-www redirect to www

Comment: @redhatengineer6 That's incredibly strange.  Try removing the redirecting config, and see what it's doing then?

Comment: ok when i remove the redirecting config.. with all three with www...no redirecting now and the www goes to the real content but then non-www goes to default lighttpd page for all excpet web3.com still shows error 500 and 503. Now with www all three go to default lighttpd page..one more thing i had to like reboot the machine and even still there was still cached files so had to delete every cache in firefox to be able to see this...reloaded shut down server and so on but still couldn;t load the real current pages until delete all history..so yeah that what i got

Comment: another weird discovery...ok when i clear all history on firefox..it starts displaying separate www and non-www as explained above but then after i try www then it starts to redirect non-www now to www...and when i clear history again it starts all over again showing them separate and then back to redirecting to www..i just don't get this...lighttpd had been a pain seriosuly..apache and nginx gave me no issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

[this steps work on alpine linux](https://blog.tian.it/lighttpd-and-virtualhosts/)

load fine laravel, slim and codeigniter

```
uncomment:       "mod_rewrite",
uncomment:       "mod_simple_vhost",

var.basedir  = "/var/www/localhost"
server.document-root = var.basedir + "/htdocs"
```

the next 3 lines make the magic!

```
simple-vhost.server-root = "/var/www/localhost/htdocs/vhost"
simple-vhost.default-host = "myhost1.com"
simple-vhost.document-root = "/public"
```

config rewrite

```
url.rewrite-if-not-file = ("(.*)" => "/index.php/$0")
```

for each host create a folder for example:

```
myhost1.com    /var/www/localhost/htdocs/vhost/myhost1.com
otherhost.com    /var/www/localhost/htdocs/vhost/otherhost.com
```

add your host to /etc/hosts file

```
127.0.0.1  myhost1.com
127.0.0.1  otherhost.com
```

reload lighttpd

```
rc-service -vv lighttpd restart
```